# Is my betta aggressive? Can she share a tank with other bettas or mollys?

Tags: aggression, betta, community-aquarium

A few months ago I had a male betta (separate tanks) pass away. I had him since I was 9, I'm currently 20.

So eight months ago I adopted my fifth betta. A veiltale female. Violet.

My mom and grandma BOTH gave me bettas for my birthday (a few weeks ago). I considered doing a female sorority. All are the same breed, the two newbies got along but violet, instantly flared and would corner them. I pulled her out and didn't try again.

They are both in 5 gallon tanks. I just got three mollys. I put her in and it was fine until one got too close. Now all she does is flare. It's been less than 3 hours. Is it okay to put her in the tank with the mollys?

I had her floating with them before to adjust. Both are in a new 10 gal tank. She is currently separate by a breeder, she still flares at that one molly. What do I do? Should I separate them and put her in my extra ten gal? Or try at one of my other younger bettas? I feel abusive leaving her in the breeder. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Bettas are semi-aggressive fish which means that they are temperamental towards certain kinds of fish. Bettas shouldn't be housed with other male betta's since they will fight until one of them is dead. They can however live with female bettas but it's about a 50/50 chance of it working out.

As far as other fish, they can definitely live with other tropical community fish. You wouldn't want to put them with fish that have long fins since the betta will attack the fins to the point of them no longer being able to swim. The best situation to have a betta with multiple kinds of fish would to be a bigger tank such as a minimum 10 gallon tank, put lots of plants and decorations.

There is a huge common misconception that if there are too many plants/decor that the fish will hide when that isn't the case. The more you have, the more confident your fish will be to swim everywhere in the tank. Also bettas are turbulent sensitive so the less the water moves from the filter running or air bubblers the better, again lots of plants will help solve that problem as well.

The fish you'd like to mix with your betta would be, mollies, platys, any of the rainbow fish family, cory catfish (must be schooled at least 3 minimum), tetras.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, so you have 3 female bettas?

Usually female betta fish get along with other species, but sometimes female betta fish can be a bit aggressive.

It is okay for your female, Violet to flare at the other fish and give a warning peck or two. That's her way of saying "I'm a loner! Leave me alone! I need space!". It may also be that Violet has never encountered this species of fish before (they wouldn't be found together in the wild) and is unsure of what to do. I bet you will discover that she calms down in a week or two.

However, if Violet becomes more violent than that, say, chasing them around the tank or repeatedly pecking at other fish or their fins, then you should separate Violet into her own tank, or consider using a tank divider. This behavior is pretty rare but I've seen one or two.

Mollys are quite hardy and should be fine, but I would caution against getting any delicate breeds of fish (ex, discus species) with an aggressive-tempered fish like Violent.

Answer (score 0):

Betta are known to be aggressive. Specially two of them in one tank will fight each other to death. Although male and a female betta can live in harmony, they are still very feisty. They might live with other fishes in harmony but they are by nature territorial and very aggressive. I'll just leave them in a bowl of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Or, Violet is a male. I have raised bettas a couple times. For an amateur is is a challenge to separate the young males before they tear each others fins. After separating some males , I grew the rest ( mostly females with a few males) until I sold them to local shops as females. That was long ago ,today the US pet shop chains rarely buy fish from hobbyists but I expect there can still be short finned males sold as females.

Answer (score -3):

Facts About Betta

Happy Betta Facts

1. Will be active(Call there name they must respond towards you)
2. Shining Wings & healthy eyes not over tearing of there fins..
3. Will Eat happily
4. Stares back at you whichever part of room you be...:)
5. Like to sleep in corner or near heater and plants bush
6. Make Bubbles sometimes...not to much...

   Sad Betta Facts
7. Less Movement to no response in surrounding
8. Do not eat when feed
9. Dull Wings & bloaty stomach

Routine i follow,,,

1. Weekly water change
2. Feed only in evening size of there eyes  only..
3. Tempr between 75 to 78 F
4. Heater Supply
5. Tap water conditioner & Filtration bacteria to cut off the toxic effect and
   restrict growth of bacteria
6. Aquarium Salt used little amount
7. Betta dont like company but i gave her tank buddies, Platy & Tetras good
   company if your betta not over distressed....if continue keep them alone.
8. Finally always communicate with them as they are very lively and intelligent
   Pets...:)) but also can be very moody,they might get depressed easily...:(

hope above information is useful...:))

Comment: Hello and welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! Please try to read the question and answer what is asked. While your information might be useful in an article, it doesn't seem relevant. That's ok, we look forward to your next submission!

Comment: Given your experience with Betta's, the question was about an agressive Betta sharing a tank (with other Betta's or Mollys), what do you suggest?