# Betta aggressiveness

Tags: betta

I just recently got a beta and some tetras and all is going okay but we are still a bit nervous because we dont want the tetras to be killed, the betta will just swim up to one and take a look and not attack then the tetra will swim away. Is that a sign he might attack or feel stressed?

Comment: Welcome to Pets StackExchange :) Can you provide more details on how your setup? Eg - tank size, temperature, population, how established is it etc. This should help us get some answers. Generally, male bettas should be kept with nothing the same colour. They're also called 'fighting fish' for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have a male betta and 8 tetras in my 10 Gallon tank and my observation is that tetra's are quick enough to escape when  betta tries to hit. Though betta sometimes flares and tries to hit them, I did not see any tetra getting stuck by betta. They just escape in a second. I am happy that I added tetras with my betta in the tank, no worries at all and need not monitor as the tank is big enough for all the fishes to stay happily together. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Betta's and tetra's are often kept together without any problems. 
In general they only become aggressive against fish with long fins (like a male guppy), or if the tank is overcrowded,  especially with fish that also swim in the top layer.

Have a look at the answer here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/19602/7038